# Minimum order amount in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, currency, checkout

I use Opencart 1.5.5.1 and I have a problem. I want in my store minimun order amount. But I am using two currencies (EUR & RON). Well, the scripts that I've added works great, but when I switch from EUR to RON the script doesn't change.

EX. Order min in EUR is 230 and in RON is 1000.
When I order products about 250E the message doesn't appear. But my checkout must redirect in RON currency. ($this->currency->set('RON');) 
And the message apear. "You must order > 1000 RON" but conversion from EUR to RON is equal or bigger.

Here is my code to understand it:

```
<?php if($this->session->data['currency'] == 'EUR') : ?>
   <?php if($this->cart->getSubtotal() < 230) : ?>
   <div class="warning"><center><?php echo $text_comandamin_eur; ?></center></div>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php } elseif($this->session->data['currency'] == 'RON') : ?>
   <?php if($this->cart->getSubtotal() < 1000) : ?>
   <div class="warning"><center><?php echo $text_comandamin_ron; ?></center></div>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you setting the currency to USD instead of RON?

Comment: Your code is very difficult to read with all the php tags on every line, but I think you are ending your first currency check instead of doing an else if.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<?php if($this->session->data['currency'] == 'EUR') : ?>
    <?php if($this->cart->getSubtotal() < 230) : ?>
    <div class="warning"><center><?php echo $text_comandamin_eur; ?></center></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } elseif($this->session->data['currency'] == 'RON') : ?>
    <?php if($this->cart->getSubtotal() < 1000) : ?>
    <div class="warning"><center><?php echo $text_comandamin_ron; ?></center></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It's easier to read using less than because you do not have an empty if statement.

Comment: besides readability, is there any other reason for the alternate syntax?

Comment: @shadyyx i am not good in opencart, kindly let me know in which file i have to add this code